# Update Twitter Status Error

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, status

I am updating twitter status using my application and facing a problem.

```
stdClass Object ( [request] => /1/statuses/update.json [error] => Could not authenticate you. )
```

But i have authenticate just 2 minutes ago and again its showing same error using code given bellow.

```
if(strlen($status)>=140)
    {
        $status = substr($status,0,139);
    }
    if($E_oauth_token != "" && $E_oauth_token_secret != "")
    {
        try
        {
            $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $E_oauth_token, $E_oauth_token_secret);
            $access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($tweet_verifier);
            $params = array('status' =>  $status);
            print_r($twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', $params));
        }
        catch(exception $e)
        {
              echo $e;
        }
```

Comment: Again i have authorize application and update one status for next status it says could not authenticate you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this and explain on this site you can easily check.

There is two types of oauth tokens one is temporary and with that temporary we have to get permanent token explained here [Twitter OAuth in PHP](http://www.phpgang.com/twitter-oauth-in-php_175.html).